# Neutrino oscillation probability phase difference

Tags: neutrinos

[image: Muon neutrino oscillations, short range [(Wikipedia)]

So I found the graph above, as well as several others showing similar phenomena, in the wikipedia article for neutrino oscillations, and it quite clearly shows a phase difference between the oscillations from a muon neutrino (blue) to a tau (red) and electron (black). At the second oscillation probability peaks this has already reached a range of about 200 km/GeV.

However, when looking at the formula for the oscillation probabilities I don't see anything that should change this (assuming no CP-violation):

$P_{\alpha \to \beta} = \delta_{\alpha \beta} - 4\sum_{i>j} \text{Re}(U_{\alpha i}^* U_{\beta i} U_{\alpha j} U_{\beta j}^*)\sin^2\left(\frac{\Delta m^2_{ij}L}{4E} \right)$.

The matrix elements only serve to change the amplitude of the oscillation and have nothing to do with the frequency of the oscillation itself. Thus, the only factor I can think of that could result in this would be the minor difference in the mass deltas $\Delta m^2_{1,3}$ and $\Delta m^2_{2,3}$ between the mass states. However, this difference is about $\frac{1}{30}$, far too small to make such a major difference so quickly - and besides, this graph was made using the approximation $\Delta m^2_{1,3} = \Delta m^2_{2,3}$.

Obviously I'm missing something, but what is that?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention I'm talking about the phase difference between the $\nu_{\mu} \to \nu_{\tau}$ (red) and $\nu_{\mu} \to \nu_{e}$ (black) probabilities! That's the entire point of the question. Sorry about that!

**EDIT 2:** Doing the calculations without the assumption $\Delta m_{1,2}^2 = \Delta m^2_{1,3}$ I get the exact result shown in these plots, so I assume it is actually an incorrectly labelled approximation.

Comment: That's because a plot of $1-\sin^2{x}$ and $\sin^2{x}$ are out of phase by 90 degrees.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant the phase difference between the probability of a transition to a tauon neutrino and an electron neutrino!

Comment: @whyamidoingthis Hello, I definitively agree with the explanation of Triatticus : the shift that you see between $\nu_\tau$ and $\nu_\mu$ is constant, and just due to the negative sign in the formula for $\nu_\mu\rightarrow \nu_\mu$ ($1- A*sin(...t)$) with respect to formula for  $\nu_\mu\rightarrow \nu_\tau$, $(A*sin(...t))$, thus if you remove the sign - and replace with it with $\pi/2$, you will find exactly the shift. So everything looks fine.

Comment: I am not asking about the phase between the $\nu_{\mu}$ and $\nu_{\tau}$, but the small one between $\nu_{e}$ and $\nu_{\tau}$ - the peak for the $\nu_{\mu} \to \nu_{e}$ (black in graph) comes slightly earlier than $\nu_{\mu} \to \nu_{e}$ (red in graph). That's what's confusing me.